# Button click should redirect another page based on dropdown selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have form1 with textbox and dropdownlist box. When the drop downlist is selected and I click the button it should redirect to form2.
I have answers only for redirection of webpage once the ddl list item is selected not during the button click after selection.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

In the View

```
<asp:Button ID="myId" runat="server" onclick="myButton_Click"/>
```

In the CodeBehind

```
protected void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              Response.Redirect("form2.aspx");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Kinda unclear on this part.

"I have answers only for redirection of webpage once the ddl list item is selected not during the button click after selection"

If what you mean is the display on form2 is based on the value of dropdownlist from form1, you can use session or request.querystring.

But if what you mean is dropdownlist must have a selected value before redirecting to form2, then you can check if it has selected value on click event of button.